# Are there libraries based on qiskit that can trace over unentangled qubits?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Suppose I have a `QuantumCircuit` object `qc`, which contains some unentangled qubits, and a Hamiltonian whose expectation value I want to measure with respect to the state prepared by `qc`. Here is a minimum example :

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
qr = QuantumRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr)
qc.x(1)
Ham = SparsePauliOp(["ZI"], coeffs=[1])
```

As the two qubits of `qc` are not entangled, I can trace out either of them. For instance, since $\langle 1 | \sigma_Z | 1 \rangle =-1$, we can trace the leading qubit of the above circuit, and construct the reduced Hamiltonian

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
qr_reduced = QuantumRegister(1)
qc_reduced = QuantumCircuit(qr_reduced)
Ham_reduced = SparsePauliOp(["I"], coeffs=[-1])
```

These two systems will have the same expectation values.

I am curious to know, whether there are any python packages (ideally based on qiskit) that can trace out unentangled qubits this way?

Comment: On a simulator or real quantum computer you will basically ignore the results of those qubits. If you want an analytical way you basically need a partial trace function, this is implemented in QuTiP.